# Setting ID in Stibo Step

Tags: javascript

I want to assign value of one attribute as ID in Stibo Step. They don't have function to set ID. Is there any other way to do it?

Tried default functions

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please provide more details and code you have tried . At the moment your question is not clear at all . Also provide some context and what stibo step is

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the IDs in STEP. You can only assign value to the ID when creating a new object.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34861529)